# Custom jQuery method creation

Tags: jquery, methods, scope, this

I want to create a function or method that can be run on jQuery objects. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8k22/).

```
$(function() {

    $("#myElem").click(function(){ 
        $(this).myMethod("red");       
    });

    var myMethod = function(myParam){
        var buttonBorder = "2px solid " + myParam;
        $(this).css("border", buttonBorder);
    };

});
```

The first problem is that the method isn't working as I expected. I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'myMethod'
```

The second problem (perhaps caused by the first?) is that `$(this)` in `myMethod` is not the same as `$(this)` in the event handler. Is there a way for the method to get the object without explicitly passing it as a parameter?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a plugin you have to add it to `jQuery.fn`:

```
$.fn.myMethod = function(myParam){
    var buttonBorder = "2px solid " + myParam;
    $(this).css("border", buttonBorder);
};
```

Now you can call it the way you want to and `this` will also reference the right context.
See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8k22/1/).

Comment: According to the authoring page, in a jQuery function, `this` is already a jQuery object. No need to do `$(this)`: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: There is always somebody pointing that out. You are right. But for the sake of consistency I usually wrap it. Can save you a lot of headache for the cases where `this` is *not* a jQuery object but you think it is.

Comment: If even the jQuery documentation about plugin authoring points it out,  I think it is important to try and follow their example. I know that people are bound to mess something up somewhere but if they never make the mistake and always do it some less efficient way, how will they learn?

Comment: +1 TheZ, `$.fn` is simply a shorthand to `jQuery.prototype`, meaning `this` always references a jQuery object, until you call another jQuery method on it e.g. `.each` where inside its function scope `this` will reference the element being iterated.

Comment: While I agree that it is important to know you already pointed out the issue. Once you are calling `this.each(function() {})`, for example, `this` in the callback will be an HTML element and *not* jQuery wrapped. You can avoid problems with something like that by being consistent. I doubt that the additional wrapping will ever cause any significant performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to functions you can assign more than one argument:

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu3Ds/1/)

- The desired element
- The color to use

```
 function myMethod(el, color){
    $(el).on('click',function(){
        this.css("border", "2px solid " + color);
    });
 }   
   
 myMethod("#myElem", "red");
```

But I suggest you to create a **plugin.**

**[plugin version](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu3Ds/3/)**

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myMethod = function( arg ) {
      this.on('click',function(){
          $(this).css({border:'2px solid '+ arg });
      });
  };
})( jQuery );

$("#myElem").myMethod('blue');
```

**[Or like this if you prefer:](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu3Ds/5/)**

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.myMethod = function( arg ) {
          this.css({border:'2px solid '+ arg });
    };
})( jQuery );
    
        
$("#myElem").on('click',function(){
    $(this).myMethod('blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### You $.fn what?

You can't monkey patch something into jQuery like that, you need to use the fn methods, detailed extensively here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring